# How can I show the root taxonomy term in a view field in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a **view** with a taxonomy term field called Location in Drupal 7 and I want to show the **first / root level of the term hierarchy** in each view item field, aka the Country level.

My Location field in **not mandatory**, so I also want to show items with no Location. Meaning that I should mark all my term relationships as **not required**.

I have tried using **relationship** to the taxonomy term, and to the parent of the taxonomy term. And then a parent filter on the parent of the taxonomy term with value = empty. By this way I managed to show the root level of my taxonomy field only, but not items with no Location. As trying to make my relationship on taxonomy term not required, throws an exception. I guess this is due to the fact that then it tries to find the parent of the term and if it the term is empty, it throws the exception.

Any suggestions on how could I show the root term (Country) and, at the same time, items with no Location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'Fields' section of the view add your taxonomy field (Location). Select the Formatter that you want and then in the settings of the field, in the fieldset 'Multiple field settings' change the 'Display' option from 'all' to '1'.

Enjoy

Comment: It worked! I thought that this option was for multiple values fields only, but it works also for multi-level taxonomy term fields also, regarding each level as a separate value. So, in single-value taxonomy term fields this solution works fine and even with empty values. Moreover, it is easy to implement and does not require relationships.